# Getting feature importances out of an Adaboosted linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, adaboost

I have the following code:

```
modelClf = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression(), learning_rate=2, n_estimators=427, random_state=42)

modelClf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

While trying to interpret and improve the results, I wanted to see the feature importances, however I get an error saying that linear regressions don't really do that kind of thing.

Alright, sounds reasonable, so I tried using .coef_ since it should work for linear regressions, but it, in place, turned out incompatible with the adaboost regressor.

Is there any way to find the feature importances or is it impossible when adaboost it used on a linear regression?

Comment: rest of the code, or are we guesing that ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

[Issue12137](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12137) suggests to add support for this using the `coefs_`, although a choice needs to be made how to normalize negative coefficients.  There's also [the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422769/232706) of when coefficients are really good representatives of importance (you should at least scale your data first).  And then there's [the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/483796/232706) of when adaptive boosting helps a linear model in the first place.

One way to do this quickly is to modify the `LinearRegression` class:

```py
class MyLinReg(LinearRegression):
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self.coef_  # assuming one output

modelClf = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=MyLinReg(), ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Checked with below code, there is an attribute for feature importance:

```html
import pandas as pd
import random 
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':random.choices(range(0, 100), k=10), 'x2':random.choices(range(0, 100), k=10)})

df['y'] = df['x2'] * .5

X = df[['x1','x2']].values
y = df['y'].values

regr = AdaBoostRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=100)
regr.fit(X, y)

regr.feature_importances_
```

Output: You can see feature 2 is more important as Y is nothing but half of it (as the data is created in such way).

[image]